# open sans regular font not working as expected in iOS 7

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm new to iOS programming .. trying to use fonts in my application. While doing so I'm stuck at one step.
I have downloaded Google's Open-Sans family fonts. Except the Open-Sans Regular, all fonts are working fine.. This is driving me crazy now ..

I have followed all the steps which are required to add a font into the project's directory.

Comment: how are you calling it...

Comment: Questions about code should include code.

Comment: I'm calling it by using [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:s].. and i got to know that font with name should be font name and not the file name . But still its not working for OpenSans-Regular.ttf file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's either:

1. Not included in the target (click on `OpenSans-Regular.ttf` and check if target membership includes your app)
2. Not included in Info.plist under `Fonts provided by application`
3. Font name misspelled (for regular use `[UIFont fontWithName:"OpenSans" size:size];`, without "-Regular" par or spaces between open and sans)

Comment: Point#3 solved my problem, I had to just use "OpenSans" instead of "OpenSans-Regular" this was driving me nuts. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

**Extra bold is not available for OpenSans**

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

So Try OpenSans or OpenSans-Semibold
example:-

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:16.0f];
```